# preprocessing for TaskScheduler-Library doesn't work - multiple definition Error

Tags: c++, arduino, scheduled-tasks

I'm facing problems getting multiple definition errors for an entire Library. As soon as I include the [TaskScheduler](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TaskScheduler) library in another header-file (except the .ino) I get the error.

For clarification: below is not my actual code that I want to be fixed! I reduced it to the minimum that still has the error (tested in Eclipse sloeber and Arduino IDE):

**Project.ino:**

```
#include <TaskScheduler.h>
#include "WifiHelper.h"

void setup(){}
void loop(){}
```

**WifiHelper.h :**

```
#ifndef WIFIHELPER_H_
#define WIFIHELPER_H_

#include <TaskScheduler.h>

#endif /* WIFIHELPER_H_ */
```

**WifiHelper.cpp:**

```
#include "Wifihelper.h"
```

You can download the project [here](https://gitlab.com/narjesmieke/project).

So why do I need to include `TaskScheduler.h` twice here? Well, the class `WifiHelper.h` receives a pointer of type `Scheduler` and initiates a `Task` with it in the file `WifiHelper.cpp` in its constructor `WifiHelper::WifiHelper(std::shared_prt<Scheduler> scheduler){...}`.

The `TaskScheduler.h` has a preprocessor-statement and I really don't get why I'm facing this problem here. In my original project I'm using several other libraries included as stated above and everything works fine. I'm wondering if this is an issue with the library.

Part of the error message:

```
'Starting combiner'
"C:/Users/Mimi/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/tools/xtensa/esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc" -nostdlib "-LC:/Users/Mimi/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/tools/sdk/lib" "-LC:/Users/Mimi/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/tools/sdk/ld" -T esp32_out.ld -T esp32.common.ld -T esp32.rom.ld -T esp32.peripherals.ld -T esp32.rom.spiram_incompatible_fns.ld -u ld_include_panic_highint_hdl -u call_user_start_cpu0 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-static -Wl,- undefined=uxTopUsedPriority -u __cxa_guard_dummy -u __cxx_fatal_exception -Wl,--start-group    .\WifiHelper.cpp.o .\sloeber.ino.cpp.o   "C:/Users/Mimi/eclipse-workspaces/esp32/Project2/Release/arduino.ar" -lgcc -lopenssl -lbtdm_app -lfatfs -lwps -lcoexist -lwear_levelling -lhal -lnewlib -ldriver -lbootloader_support -lpp -lmesh -lsmartconfig -ljsmn -lwpa -lethernet -lphy -lapp_trace -lconsole -lulp -lwpa_supplicant -lfreertos -lbt -lmicro-ecc -lcxx -lxtensa-debug-module -lmdns -lvfs -lsoc -lcore -lsdmmc -lcoap -ltcpip_adapter -lc_nano -lrtc -lspi_flash -lwpa2 -lesp32 -lapp_update -lnghttp -lspiffs -lespnow -lnvs_flash -lesp_adc_cal -llog -lexpat -lm -lc -lheap -lmbedtls -llwip -lnet80211 -lpthread -ljson -lstdc++ -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-EL -o "C:/Users/Mimi/eclipse-workspaces/esp32/Project2/Release/Project2.elf" C:/Users/Mimi/eclipse-workspaces/esp32/Project2/Release/arduino.ar
.\sloeber.ino.cpp.o: In function `Task::isEnabled()':
C:\Users\Mimi\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TaskScheduler\src/TaskScheduler.h:312: multiple definition of `Task::isEnabled()'
.\WifiHelper.cpp.o:C:\Users\Mimi\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TaskScheduler\src/TaskScheduler.h:312: first defined here
.\sloeber.ino.cpp.o: In function `Task::getInterval()':
sloeber.ino.cpp:(.text._ZN4Task11getIntervalEv+0x0): multiple definition of `Task::getInterval()'
.\WifiHelper.cpp.o:WifiHelper.cpp:(.text._ZN4Task11getIntervalEv+0x0): first defined here
.\sloeber.ino.cpp.o: In function `Task::getIterations()':
```

and so on and so forth - if you want to see the full message click [here](https://pastebin.com/bkFmH4sL)...don't get confused by the "Project2.ino" in the end. I simply tried it in another project with the same files.

Comment: What's the error message? Please copy it here.

Comment: @battlmonstr here you go - just like every "multiple-defined" error message x'D Only I don't understand why I'm getting it here

Comment: Please post the full message somewhere (like pastebin.com ).

Comment: @battlmonstr well if you think it helps :/ Its simply the whole library

Comment: Isn't it because you include "TaskScheduler.h" twice? Once in Project.ino and once in WifiHelper.h?
Try removing it from either of those.

Comment: well, yes. It compiles if I remove one of these. But in my actual Project I need it included in both as they both use Objects from type Task. Every use of Task or else from TaskScheduler happens within a defined class. If I remove the include-statement from WifiHelper it simply cannot resolve these types in WifiHelper.cpp

Comment: What if you remove from Project.ino, but keep in WifiHelper.h, will it work then?

Comment: I mean keep in WifiHelper.h, because it is included transitively in Project.ino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C/C++ if you define a function inside 2 separate "translation modules" (i.e. ".cpp" files), you will get this error, because the linker doesn't know which one to use for the final program.

You Project.ino seems to compile as it's own translation module - "sloeber.ino.cpp", so if you have the same function definition included in both `WifiHelper.cpp` and `sloeber.ino.cpp` you will get this error.

First make sure that you don't include stuff twice.
To be absolutely sure you can add guards around your `#include`:

```
#ifndef TASK_SCHEDULER_H_INCLUDED
#define TASK_SCHEDULER_H_INCLUDED
#include <TaskScheduler.h>
#endif // TASK_SCHEDULER_H_INCLUDED
```

Looking at the source code here - https://github.com/arkhipenko/TaskScheduler/blob/master/src/TaskScheduler.h

this was clearly not meant to be included twice.

But there's another file there - [TaskSchedulerDeclarations.h](https://github.com/arkhipenko/TaskScheduler/blob/master/src/TaskSchedulerDeclarations.h), which might be included multiple times, so maybe try to use that file in your other files.

If that doesn't help, there are other workarounds:

1. move library function definitions from .h file to .cpp files, and only keep function declarations inside .h files (this might be a lot of work though)
2. or add "static" in front of the function definitions, which would render them as local to the translation module (single cpp file), in this case it is not an error to have multiple of them in the whole program.

Comment: thank you for these suggestions. so far I added the guards and tried to add the include-statements to the `cpp`instead of `h`File - neither worked unfortunately. I also did remove the `sloeber.ino`and exectued this code on the arduino IDE - but I get the same `error`but with `sketch/...` instead of referencing the `sloeber.ino`. I'll go on and try your other suggestions later

Comment: You should probably post an issue for the library author here - https://github.com/arkhipenko/TaskScheduler/issues

Comment: There's a 2nd file - TaskSchedulerDeclarations.h maybe try to use that instead for using the tasks inside other files?

Comment: that works really well, Thank you for that hint.
I'll post an issue anyways. 

Would you mind adding the suggestion with `TaskSchedulerDeclarations.h` to your answer that I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: Good. I've edited the answer to include TaskSchedulerDeclarations.h